# Wordpress custom search results page

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to create a custom search results page that search's not only titles but through custom fields as well.
I've been going through the "create a search page" page in the codex but for some reason the search results done use the new **searchpage.php** code.

What I've done is create the searchform.php page with the following code:(Please notice i've added a page_id=8057 because i've added a page using the new search template.)

```
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>?page_id=8057">
  <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for(custom):</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input class="sprites" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

And i've created the searchpage.php with the default code the codex gives me:

```
<p>Search Results:</p><BR>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
       <?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>
```

I still haven't made adjustments for the code and query but i'd like to solve first the problem that the search form aint showing me the searchpage.php results but linking to the default search results page.
For example after i done a search i receive this url:

```
http://localhost/?s=mysearchquery
```

Any idea's how to get this starting?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The searchpage.php is a Search Page alternative, if you want to create a Search RESULTS page, you need to create search.php file instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the below lines at the top of your searchpage.php file

```
/*
 * Template Name: Search Results Page
 * Description: Whatever you want to write here.
 */
```

Now, go to the admin panel and create a new Page and give it a title and assign the "Search Results Page" template from the Page Attributes section on the right hand side. Don't add any content to the page.

Now, try searching, it should work.

> **Note**: The user will not land on this page if he has "typed" something in the searchbox and hits enter. This action will by default
>   redirect him to the search.php page. You can only land on
>   searchpage.php when the user has clicked on a "hyperlink" with the url
>   as

```
<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>?page_id=8057
```